# how can I check if none of the strings in a list share any characters ? (Python)

Tags: python

for example:`['AB','TC','BG','KI']` should return False and `['AB','TC','OG','KI']` should return True

I tried the naive approach of just checking every combination of 2 elements but it took way too long in the whole program so I am asking for something more efficient

Comment: Add all the letters to a set and check if the set size is the combined length of the strings?

Comment: Please show that naive approach code.

Answer (score 2):

Add all the letters to a set and check if the set size is the combined length of the strings.

```
def disjoint_strings(strings):
   all_chars = {c for string in strings for c in string}
   return len(all_chars) == sum(map(len, strings))


>>> disjoint_strings(['AB','TC','BG','KI'])
False
>>> disjoint_strings(['AB','TC','OG','KI'])
True
```

Comment: Or: `all_chars = set(''.join(strings))`

Comment: @Chris Yep that would also work 

Comment: @Chris But better use that joined string for the other half as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep a set of characters, and push into that list:

```py
def all_unique(strs: list[str]) -> bool:
    seen = set()
    for s in strs:
        for c in s:
            if c in seen:
                return False
            seen.add(c)
    return True
```

Comment: Good that this stops and returns False as soon as it finds a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate them into one string, then use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the characters. If any have a count higher than one, return `False`.

Or avoid the string concatenation by just passing a generator expression to `Counter`.

```
>>> lst = ['AB','TC','BG','KI']
>>> Counter(c for s in lst for c in s)
Counter({'B': 2, 'A': 1, 'T': 1, 'C': 1, 'G': 1, 'K': 1, 'I': 1})
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot the final check.

Comment: I wasn't aiming to provide a complete solution when the question hasn't demonstrated the OP's effort.